# What is "section" in "__PCPU_ATTRS" of kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am studying the code in Linux Kernel. Especially, [Per-CPU variables](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Concepts/per-cpu.html).

I have a question about `section` in the [following part](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/source/include/linux/percpu-defs.h#L48).

```
#define __PCPU_ATTRS(sec)                       \
    __percpu __attribute__((section(PER_CPU_BASE_SECTION sec))) \
    PER_CPU_ATTRIBUTES
```

Usually, I use `http://elixir.free-electrons.com/` to find variable definition. But sometimes it is hard to find the real one.

In this case, what is `section` [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13.4/ident/section)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case `section` is a variable attribute. It's a compiler-specific construct, not a symbol name to look for on the site.

Roughly, it just allows one to choose in what exact section shall the object be placed. I.e., normally the compiler (`gcc`) places the generated objects in `data` or `bss` section of the program, but the *attribute* `section` will help you to customise that.

A more comprehensive explanation can be found in [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).